# Cascade delete is happening even though there is no foreign key relationship between 2 tables

Tags: vistadb

Lets say there are two tables Student and Address. There are no foreign key relationship between the two tables. Let me give the sample structure.

**Student TABLE**
ID, Name, AddressID, Email

**Address TABLE**
AddressID, DoorNo, Street, City, Country

The problem here is whenever I delete a record from the Student table the related entry in Address table is also getting deleted even though there is no foreign key reference.

We have thoroughly verified our dbschema scripts, there are no foreign key references. Let us know if we have to do something special in VistaDB for this.

Thanks In Advance
Murali

Comment: That's the opposite way around to how cascades typically work anyway - cascade would normally be "you delete the address, all students referencing that address are deleted".